# Shell script to truncate branch information and directories

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk, cut

Need cut/awk script to truncate the "/branches/testbranch/" and get directories path for the files but ignore the directories

```
/branches/testbranch/abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
/branches/testbranch/abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy/testBlocksCargo.java
/branches/testbranch/abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy/testBlocksCollection.java
/branches/testbranch/abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy/testBlocksPrimaryKey.java
/branches/testbranch/claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
/branches/testbranch/claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy/testBlocksGenDAO.java
/branches/testbranch/claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy/testIndexGenDAO.java
```

Desired output:

```
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
```

My script:

```
while read line
do
      change_directory=`echo "$line" | awk -F'/[^/]*$' '{sub("/branches/testbranch/","",$1)}$0=$1'`
      echo "$change_directory"
done <"test
```

Script output:

```
 abc/efg/hij/klm
 abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
 abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
 abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
 claims/returns/policy/checkmate
 claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
 claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
```

The directories and branch details changes btw

Comment: How are you distinguish the difference between file and folders? Are you saying all files will have extensions?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want (well it matches your expected output at least):

A Unix approach:

```
# Strip leading dirs based on char count
$ fgrep . file | cut -c22- | xargs -n1 dirname
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy

# Strip leading dirs based on number of dirs 
$ fgrep . file | cut -d/ -f4- | xargs -n1 dirname
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
```

An `awk` approach:

```
$ awk '/[.]/{NF--;print substr($0,22)}' FS=/ OFS=/ file
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
```

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk`:

```
 awk -F/ '$NF~/\./{for(i=4;i<(NF-1);i++) printf "%s/", $i; print $(NF-1)}' test
```

#### Test:

```
$  awk -F/ '$NF~/\./{for(i=4;i<(NF-1);i++) printf "%s/", $i; print $(NF-1)}' test
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
abc/efg/hij/klm/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
claims/returns/policy/checkmate/casestudy
```

Comment: What about files in the directory `/branches/testbranch/abc/` I don't think `NR>8` is a reasonable assumption

Comment: @sudo_O Does this look better?

Comment: `while read line
do
          change_directory=`echo "$line" | awk -F/ '$NF~/\./{for(i=4;i<(NF-1);i++) printf "%s/", $i; print $(NF-1)}'`
          echo "$change_directory"
done <"tes_new"`
 Leaves spaces in between

Comment: Why running like that. Just run the `awk` command directly on file. You don't need `while loop`. `awk` moves from line to line by default.

Comment: I need to read a file with 500+ lines and do something by ignoring the line which is a directory

Comment: You can run the `awk` command directly on the file. No need for `while loop`. Do `awk -F/ '$NF~/\./{for(i=4;i<(NF-1);i++) printf "%s/", $i; print $(NF-1)}' yourfilename` on the command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Are they real directories and files?

```bash
while read; do
    if [[ -f "$REPLY" ]]; then # Test if the input exists and is a file
        change_directory="${REPLY#/branches/testbranch/}"
        printf '%s\n' "${change_directory%/*}"
    fi
done < test
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use GNU Find and GNU Sed

Find all the files *under* testbranch, and then use sed to strip the leading part of the pathname that you wish to discard.

```
find /branches/testbranch -type f | sed 's!/branches/testbranch/!!'
```

Other versions of find and sed may or may not require modification of this pipeline. YMMV.

Comment: I think you want `! -type d` (or just `-type f`) for the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed:

```
sed -e 's#^/branches/testbranch/##' -e 's#/[^/.]*\..*$##' file
```